# Hide a add/delete button after clicking the add, In angular8

Tags: typescript, angular8

[image][![

```js
export class LeaveTypesComponent implements OnInit {
 
  hidden: boolean = false;
  
  addForm() {
    this.records = {};
    this.dataarray.push(this.records);  
    this.hidden = true; 
  }
  }
```

```html
<!--Add & Save-->
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <div class="form-group co-12">
            <div class=" click" *ngIf="!hidden">
              <!--Add Form-->
              <a (click)="addForm()"><span class="add"> <i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-2x "
                    aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a>
              <!--Remove Form-->
              <a (click)="removeForm(i)"><span class="clear"><i class="fa fa-times-circle fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </span></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9j70H.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9j70H.png)

[image: output]

When I'm clicking the add button it will generate a same form like that. But I want to hide add/delete button after clicking add but the current form it will be enable.

Comment: Just use one variable and ngIf

Comment: can you please explain it?

Comment: What is the use of `hidden` variable?

Comment: It is used for hiding the button

Comment: Then use the same logic to enable and disable also!

Comment: I already implemented the logic but It'll be hiding totally. I want to hide before the add/save button only.!

Comment: I think you need to check `*ngIf="hidden"` not `*ngIf="!hidden"`

Comment: I'm using *ngIf="!hidden"

Comment: Do you want to hide only add button after Add button click?

Comment: Nope. I want to hide add and delete button also after clicking the add button.